# array_search does not match first key

Tags: php, arrays

I have to arrays and want to look, if the items of array 1 are in array 2.

I use foreach to iterate through my array2 und check with array_search for every item, if it is array 1.

Everything works fine except that array_search always return false on the first matching key. It doesn't matter which index of array 2 the first matching key is.

I did some research but nothing worked.

Even the strict parameter does not work in my code.

```
$array1 = ["K", "L", "M"];
$array2 = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M"];

    foreach($array2 AS $data) {
        echo $data."<br>";

        if(array_search($data, $array1) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE" === false) {
            echo "TRUE<br>";
        }

        echo "<br>";
    }
```

The output of the example above is:

```
A

B

C

D

E

F

G

H

I

J

K

L
TRUE

M
TRUE
```

If i change array1 to `["B", "C", "D"]` the output is:

```
A

B

C
TRUE

D
TRUE

E

F

G

H

I

J

K

L

M
```

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: You have bad syntax in `if(array_search($data, $array1) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE" === false)` because you're not comparing against `array_search`, thus when you do the comparison against `K` you get `0`, which is falsey. Change it to `if(array_search($data, $array1) !== false ? "TRUE" : "FALSE")`

Comment: Yes, you're right, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change code like this:

```
if(array_search($data, $array1) === false) {
   echo "false<br>";
}
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/VgRFd  And https://3v4l.org/SbuZe

***Shorter way to write the same logic is:***

```
foreach($array2 AS $data) {
   echo $data .PHP_EOL. (array_search($data, $array1) !== false ? "true" : "false").PHP_EOL;
   echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output: https://3v4l.org/XTcrh

Answer (score 0):

**use in_array function**

**try**

```
$array1 = ["K", "L", "M"];
$array2 = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M"];

    foreach($array2 AS $data) {
        echo $data."<br>";

        if(in_array($data, $array1)) {
            echo "TRUE<br>";
        }

        echo "<br>";
    }
```